# Display controls on the uiview

Tags: iphone

I have this XML i want display all fields on the uiview which comes with this XML
example--i am getting "choise" meen i will display a segment control on the uiview with label and fieldname.i have parsed the xml and got all data in an array

```
- <campaign id="8aff8bbb59ac4d279dcaf1662cb20b5f">
- <input>
  <type>choice</type>  
  <fieldname>Attendance</fieldname>    
  <label>Attendance</label> 
  <validations /> 
  <selected>0</selected>    
  <params>Present,Leave,Meeting,Travel,Holiday,Weekly off</params> 
  </input>
- <input>
  <type>combo</type> 
  <fieldname>WorkingWith</fieldname> 
  <label>Working With</label> 
  <validations />  
  <selected>0</selected> 
  <params>None,ASM,RSM,ZSM</params> 
  </input>
- <input>
  <type>combo</type> 
  <fieldname>BeatName</fieldname> 
  <label>Beat Name</label> 
  <validations /> 
  <selected>0</selected> 
  <params>Lajpat Nagar,Kamala Nagar,Karol Bagh,Patel Nagar,ITO,Sector 15</params> 
  </input>
```

Comment: This post is very confusing - what is your question?  What does "choise" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi anshuman,
             if you want to get all data from xml as stated above use XML Parser and take all attributes into specific dictionary with specific key. now you have some data for particular             fields. just use XMLParser Delegate methods to detect all the data.